# How to maintain a linked list on kernel level?

Tags: kernel, freebsd

The situation is: I will implement sets of new system calls. Each of them need to access (read or write) a linked list.  So, that means I will have several C programs.

So, how can I maintain a linked list in memory and let several programs access it? Or,this is wrong....I should save it as a file? (but I hardly think this is a good idea)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am no kernel developer, but here's my guess at how to go about this...

- [sys/queue.h](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/QUEUE/) gives you macros to work with queues and linked lists.
- Provide an interface based on opaque handles so that the client programs can not change the data structure behind your back.
- Since you have multiple concurrent clients, think about protecting your interface implementation using locks.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

@jackrabbit points you into right direction. I'll add about sharing the list between syscalls.

Your code will be linked into kernel inself, or as a loadable module. Either way your data will probably need to be dynamically allocated with 'kmalloc'. This data will be available to the whole kernel, which unlike userland programs, stays resident in machine memory. Treat it as a regular pointer/data shared between (kernel) threads.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you might want to check [this](http://lwn.net/Articles/51437/) out.